# Cannot select ASP WebForms control with jQuery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I have an asp:RadioButton and try to manipulate a label according to whether it is selected or not. Using this code:

```
       if ($('.rbOpenClient').prop('checked'))
            $('.openInvLabel').addClass('radioBtnSelected');
        else if ($('rbClosedClient').prop('checked'))
            $('.closedInvLabel').addClass('radioBtnSelected');

        $('.openInvLabel').click(function () {
            $('.rbOpenClient').css('checked', true);
            $('.openInvLabel').addClass('radioBtnSelected');

            $('.rbClosedClient').css('checked', false);
            $('.closedInvLabel').removeClass('radioBtnSelected');
        });

        $('.closedInvLabel').click(function () {
            $('.rbClosedClient').prop('checked', true);
            $('.closedInvLabel').addClass('radioBtnSelected');

            $('.rbClosedClient').prop('checked', false);
            $('.openInvLabel').removeClass('radioBtnSelected');
        });
```

.rbOpenClient and .rbClosedClient are CssClass in the asp:Button. The other classes are labels.
  Do you see some problems with the jQUery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

ClientId="static"

to the asp controls should make the ids visible to JavaScript. This is because asp.bet displays a generated Id by default. The above code will enable you to use the id you gave it in the markup.

Comment: @ivan mihov, did my answer help? If so mark answer please